# Typhoeus gem not reducing response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, hydra, typhoeus

Basically I have 857 image links to check. I implemented it in 3 different methods and run them 3 times each.

**Method 1: Using Typhoeus and Hydra** (Parallel Requests)

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new(:max_concurrency => 50)
st = Time.now
@image_urls.each do |image_url|
  request = Typhoeus::Request.new(image_url)
  hydra.queue(request)
end
hydra.run
et = Time.now
puts "\n" + (et - st).to_s() + " seconds"
```

Time taken: 117.65, 99.45, 102.01 seconds

**Method 2: Using Typhoeus** (Singular Request)

```
st = Time.now
@image_urls.each do |image_url|
  response = Typhoeus::Request.head(image_url)
end
et = Time.now
puts "\n" + (et - st).to_s() + " seconds"
```

Time taken: 33.85, 31.89, 30.18 seconds

**Method 3: Using Net::HTTP Ruby library**

```
st = Time.now
@image_urls.each do |image_url|
  url = URI.parse(image_url)
  req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
  res = req.request_head(url.path).code   
end
et = Time.now
puts "\n" + (et - st).to_s() + " seconds"
```

Time taken: 83.30, 67.62, 75.26 seconds

Initially I thought **Method 1: Typhoeus and Hydra** is suppose to speed up Http response time by sending parallel requests instead of sending 1 at a time. However, the above result show me that I am in fact getting a slower response time.

One reason could be a http request for the header has lesser overhead than a normal http GET request. Other than that, am I doing something wrong here? Need advice to optimize this process, I just need to retrieve the http status code.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, you'll definitely want to benchmark using the same HTTP method. HEAD requests will tend to return much more quickly than GET requests.

If having a few false positives isn't a deal-breaker, you might want to try lowering connect/response timeouts. If accuracy is paramount, lower the max concurrency (try 10-15) and take advantage of [`Typhoeus::Request#on_complete`](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus/blob/master/lib/typhoeus/request.rb#L157) to do HTTP status code processing.